# Hidden column breaks layout of following row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a layout with three rows.  I would like the first row to have one column that spans all 12 columns at the xs size.  At larger sizes I would like two columns, one 9 columns wide and one 3 columns wide.  I have attempted this by adding the second column and making it hidden at xs and visible and 3 wide at sm.

However, doing so breaks the layout of my second row at larger screen sizes for some reason. I'm not sure why.

Code working before adding hidden column:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">



  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <link href="../styles/StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">

      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div id="header">

          <h1>This will be the page header</h1>
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="No_Sidebar.html">Page w/o Sidebar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>


    <div class="row-fluid">

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-sm-push-9">
        <div id="side-bar">
          This is the side bar
          <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item active">item a</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">item b</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">item c</li>
                </ul>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-sm-pull-3">
        <div id="content">
          <h2>This is the main content</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="col-xs-12">

        <div id="footer">
          This is the footer
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>


  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Code broken after adding hidden column:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">



  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <link href="../styles/StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
        <div id="header">

          <h1>This will be the page header</h1>

          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="Home.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="No_Sidebar.html">Page w/o Sidebar</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-3 visible-sm ">

      </div>

    </div>


    <div class="row-fluid">

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-sm-push-9">
        <div id="side-bar">
          This is the side bar
          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item active">item a</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">item b</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">item c</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-sm-pull-3">
        <div id="content">
          <h2>This is the main content</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="col-xs-12">

        <div id="footer">
          This is the footer
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>


  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have figured out the solution.  I'm setting the column that I want hidden as visible on small, medium, and large, and setting it to 3 columns on small screens or larger.

I also added a div between the rows with the clearfix class.

```html
<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
        <div id="header">

          <h1>This will be the page header</h1>

          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="Home.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="No_Sidebar.html">Page w/o Sidebar</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg col-sm-3">
        <div id="logo">
          <p>This is the hidden area</p>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="row-fluid">
      <!-- rest of the code from before -->
```